# Displaying data from different tables in MySql Database into vb.net 2012 Textboxes

Tags: mysql, vb.net

am trying to run some lines of code to enable me display some data from different tables from MySql database in vb.net 2012. This is how it works. When i login with my username and password, it should display the name of my store and branch name in the text box provided using my login details. This code is not written in the login form. below is my code

```vb
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class SelectionForm

    Dim sqlconn As MySqlConnection
    Dim sqlcmd As MySqlCommand


    Private Sub SelectionForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        sqlconn = New MySqlConnection
        sqlconn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=;database=osap"

        Dim sqlreader As MySqlDataReader
        'Dim sqladapter As MySqlDataAdapter

        Try
            sqlconn.Open()
            Dim Query As String
            Query = "SELECT sales_reps.username, stores.name, branches.name FROM sales_reps, stores, branches WHERE sales_reps.id =(SELECT id FROM sales_reps WHERE username='" & LoginForm.UserTextBox.Text & "' AND password='" & LoginForm.PassTextBox.Text & "') AND branches.id = sales_reps.branch_id AND stores.id = branches.store_id"
            sqlcmd = New MySqlCommand(Query, sqlconn)

            sqlreader = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader()

            If sqlreader.HasRows Then
                sqlreader.Read()
                BranchTextBox.Text = sqlreader.GetString("branches.name")
                StoreTextBox.Text = sqlreader.GetString("stores.name")

            End If

            sqlconn.Close()

        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

        Finally
            sqlconn.Dispose()
        End Try

    End Sub
End Class
```

No errors are displayed but doesn't show the data in the text boxes either.

Comment: Dont glue bits of strings together to create a SQL query - use Parameters. Also, there is nothing reusable about a DbCommand object and you are creating a new one each time anyway.  Create use and dispose of the Connection and COmmand objects each time.  Set a breakpoint and see `If sqlreader.HasRows` in fact has rows

Comment: Thank you @plutonix.I will try that out.